# How do you say "in all directions" in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Consider the following example sentence:

> Sound is a form of energy that travels **in all directions**.

How to do you say "in all directions" (which is shown as bold in example sentence) in a single word? There's even shorter than that (all around):

> Sound is a form of energy that travels **all around**.

I have a single word "[round](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/round)" [adverb]:

> Sound is a form of energy that travels **round**.

... which doesn't satisfy me at all, as it denotes a circular motion:

> **ADVERB**
>   1. so as to rotate or cause
>   rotation; with circular
>   motion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87889/discussion-on-question-by-ahmed-how-do-you-say-in-all-directions-in-a-single-w).

Comment: What is the context in which you need to express this in a single word?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You could use [omnidirectionally](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnidirectionally), though it might sound a bit too technical.

Alternatively, "everywhere" could also be used.

Note 1: Just in case the link above stops working, according to Oxford Dictionaries (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omnidirectionally) "omnidirectionally" means, precisely, "in all directions".

Note 2: Where I said above that the word might sound too technical, I was speaking from a linguistic point of view, in full agreement with some members' view of the word provided as "awful". However, this is ELU, not an engineering site, and if there is a mistake, it lies with the original sentence which refers to the sound travelling in **all** directions. I'm not interested in engineering here but in providing an answer to the question which, I remind you, is **how to say *in all directions* in a single word**. The prefix *omni-* means "all", just like the original sentence: therefore, I merely answered what was asked.

Comment: Correct... But unfortunately quite awful. Ironically, this single word is also longer than the original three words.

Answer (score 22):

A common everyday adverb is **[radially](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/radially)**

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/radially) "in a way that spreads out from a central point"
Example: *Gravitational field lines spread out radially from the centre of the Earth.*

Whilst it is most often applied in a planar 2D fashion, it can equally be applied to describe travel to or from a point in 3D.

> Sound is a form of energy that travels **radially**.

see [Radially Propagating Sound Waves](https://sciencesims.com/sims/soundwaves-cyl/) note that since the web is not yet 3D this sample will look like its seen by a flat earth observer. and for the record here is an image of an  **omnidirectional radially quaquaversal** sound wave.

[image]

Technically for radio an [Omnidirectional antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnidirectional_antenna) radiates toroidally about one axis. I have also seen omnidirectional also applied to microphones that pick up and speakers that emanate, sound from all around at one level.
"What is meant by omnidirectional when it comes to sound? ... sound from all directions around it.... Although claiming to be omnidirectional, none of them are really spherical."
[image]

Comment: @Chemomechanics In the OP’s example, I think *radially* works very well. In that context, “from the source” is strongly implied: there’s no other natural point of emanation.

Comment: Really interesting thing .... unfortunately I think radially inevitably and always means *in a flat plane*.  I don't think I have ever seen it used to mean spherically.  So, the "Earth" example quoted here from Cambridge is, for me - simply wrong!   For me the linked animation indeed shows a radial (2d!) plane of interest!  I think at best we can say using "radially is dangerous, since, it almost always is used in a planar sense."

Comment: Radially is modifying quaquaversal in this sentence.  Omnidirectional is the word meaning in all directions

Comment: The problem with "radially" is that it only implies an orientation of one set to another set, it doesn't fully describe the set. In other words, a single vector coming out of a source point is "emitting radially" (versus tangential). It sounds like what the OP meant in the question was, "the set of all radial vectors." If you shoot a laser from the center of a sphere, it's emitting *radially*. But that's not the same as, say, soundwaves, which are emitting *in all directions* from the source.

Comment: I don't mean to contrast light vs sound physically, but rather the fact that "radial" implies a spatial relationship between two sets, and does not fully describe the set or imply "in **all** directions." Radial does not mean "in all directions," it just means a straight line from a focus that's perpendicular to a curve. You're right, the soundwaves move radially - that is not incorrect. But if you're specifically trying to imply "in all directions" then "omnidirectionally" is more accurate. Saying "X moves radially" can apply to lots of things that are NOT omnidirectional.

Comment: This is a fantastic choice. It even works in technical contexts. You might want to give a mention to alternate wordings using "radiates." @Chemomechanics When unspecified, it will be understood that it's radially from some center of interest. It's not going to be confusing.

Comment: "radially"  is plain wrong. (1) Radiality is not sufficient: It is missing the, well, *omni* aspect. ["Occasionally bicycles will have completely radial spokes"](https://www.exploratorium.edu/cycling/wheel2.html) but they are surely not protruding omnidirectionally from the hub. (2) Radiality is not even necessary: In a room with uniformly glowing walls the light rays will be omnidirectional but not radial.

Comment: The spherical radiation pattern, where antennas / microphones / speakers accept or emit energy in all directions *equally,* has a special word for it—isotropic. So for radio, you would say that omnidirectional antennas are not isotropic (and isotropic antennas do not even exist).

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't cover all directions, but it might be more accurate to say that sound spreads **outward** from some point.

That would seem to cover all the directions that sound generally travels, excluding odd exceptions such as sound travelling inwards or reflecting in other odd directions.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outward), "outward":

> adverb: 1. toward the outside
>
> adjective: 1. moving, directed, or turned toward the outside or away from a center

Comment: *outward* does not seem to imply *in all directions*, though

Comment: Please explain in your own words why you think this answers the question. Right now it has no explanation and thus is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Isotropical(ly)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isotropic) would be an alternative for (equal) in all directions.

> exhibiting properties (such as velocity of light transmission) with the same values when measured along axes in all directions

Comment: This is wrong: firstly it's an adjective (when the OP is asking for an **adverb**), and secondly *isotropic* means much more than just "in all directions", it means "*exhibiting properties* (such as velocity of light transmission) with the same values when measured along axes in all directions" (my emphasis). There's an important semantic difference here. NB if you post a link, please add a description or quote from the source: an answer with an unexplained link risks being deleted. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Indeed, "isotropic" is just not correct here, I feel.

Comment: Yeah, I think 'isotropically' is the word here:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isotropically

From a version of that cow joke, "Assume a spherical cow in a vacuum, radiating milk isotropically".

Comment: Sorry, I should have spent more time on my answer. I will fix it.

Comment: Sound propagates isotropically only when the surrounding medium is homogeneous and isotropic and the source is motionless.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes, this goes to the heart of why *isotropically* is incorrect: the word includes additional meaning beyond the mere "in all directions" requirement. Distorted propagation (e.g. if the source is in motion) can still be "in all directions" but by definition it can't be isotropic, hence why an ambulance siren sounds different after it goes past you.

Comment: Please explain in your own words why you think this answers the question. Right now it has no explanation and thus is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

A verb, rather than an adverb, but *disperse* comes to mind:

> **disperse** (dĭ-spûrsˈ)
>
> v.    To drive off or scatter in different directions: ”The police dispersed the crowd.”
> v.    To strew or distribute widely: ”The airplane dispersed the leaflets over the city.”
> v.    To cause to vanish or disappear.

(Definitions from: https://www.wordnik.com/words/disperse)

Comment: Please explain in your own words why you think this answers the question. Right now it has no explanation and thus is not an answer.

Comment: Hi Zrajm, welcome to EL&U. I've downvoted this post because it's wrong: (1) the OP is **not** looking for a verb - the sentence "Sound is a form of energy that travels *disperse*" makes no sense; (2) *disperse* doesn't even imply *all* directions, just *different* directions; and (3) even if you used the related adverb *dispersively*, this could be problematic given the special meanings of *dispersion* in chemistry and physics. It's worthwhile to review our guidance on [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score -2):

Sound propagates **uniformly** from the source.

From Oxford Online:

> **Uniformly:** *Adverb:* With equal space between each or **in equal amounts**; evenly.

What you want to say is the **amount** of sound that propagates in any two directions are **equal**.

Comment: Sound propagates uniformly only when the surrounding medium is homogeneous and isotropic and the source is motionless.

Comment: Uniformly doesn't mean *in all directions*, it [means](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uniformly) "with equal space between each or in equal amounts; evenly" - which is quite a different thing. Daron, this is why we insist on answers with more detail, preferably citing a published definition or other reference. Six words is inadequate; your post will almost certainly end up in the Low Quality review queue, to be considered for deletion. Can I recommend you read [answer]? :-)

Answer (score -2):

**circumvent**

[From Oxford Dictionaries:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/circumvent)

> **1** to find a way around (an obstacle).
>
> **1.1**  overcome (a problem or difficulty) in a clever and surreptitious way.

Comment: Please explain in your own words why you think this answers the question. Right now it has no explanation and thus is not an answer.